# remove action listener form comboBox , but cant find parameter

Tags: java, combobox

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                switch(selected.toString()){
                        //some actions based on String picked
                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

i dont know which parameter must have .removeActionListener() method to remove action listener and change content of comboBox.

Comment: When do you want to remove the `ActionListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you've create an inline anonymous inner class, which means you have no external reference to it...

You could create the `ActionListener`, but first assign it to a instance variable

```
private ActionListener actionListener;
//...
actionListener = new ActionListener() {...};
comboBox.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

Then you could remove it later using...

```
comboBox.removeActionListener(actionListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the actionListener in a variable:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                switch(selected.toString()){
                        //some actions based on String picked
                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

and use `comboBox.removeActionListener(al)` to remove the actionListener and ofcurse you must use al for add the listener